Tmux: Swap pane with the one on the left, right, up or down
Is it possible to bind some shortcuts for swapping pane with the one on the left, right, up, bottom in opposite to prefix{ / prefix } which swap it only with previous and next panes. I'd want to swap panes as freely as you can move between them using prefix and arrow keys.
